# How to receive messages formatted by The BinaryLogFormatter

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, msmq

I'm using the MS Patterns and Practices Enterprise Library MsmqTraceListener to log entries to a private queue using the BinaryLogFormatter.

I would now like to read those log entries off the queue.  I need to set the Formatter property of the MessageQueue before I can look at the message.Body.  I expected to be able to use the BinaryLogFormatter of the EnterpriseLibrary, but I can't cast that as an IMessageFormatter. (InvalidCastException)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Enterprise Library Distributor Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647847.aspx)?  It might do what you want out of the box.  A short guide to implement: [Enterprise Library 5 Logging using MSMQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mark_bi/archive/2011/02/18/enterprise-library-5-logging-using-msmq.aspx).

If you don't want to use the full Distributor Service look at the source code to see how they access the queue.  It looks like they are deserializing using the `BinaryLogFormatter` directly.  From [MsmqLogDistributor.cs](https://entlib.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Blocks/Logging/Src/MsmqDistributor/MsmqLogDistributor.cs):

```
using (MessageQueue msmq = CreateMessageQueue())
{
    Message message = msmq.Peek();

    string serializedEntry = message.Body.ToString();

    LogEntry logEntry = null;
    try
    {
        logEntry = BinaryLogFormatter.Deserialize(serializedEntry);
    }
    catch (FormatException formatException)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (SerializationException serializationException)
    {
        ...
    }

    if (logEntry != null)
    {
        logWriter.Write(logEntry);
    }

    message = msmq.Receive();

    if (this.StopReceiving)
    {
        this.isCompleted = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to make sure to do is to include the following when setting up your messageQueue. If not the deserilizing will not work.

```
((XmlMessageFormatter)messageQueue.Formatter).TargetTypeNames = new string[] { "System.String" };
```

One waisted afternoon trying figure this one out.